# Is MsTest part of Microsoft Build Tools?

Tags: msbuild, mstest

I haven't been able to find anything about this directly online. I am about to make an automated Chocolatey script for build agent configuration.

Is MsTest part of Microsoft Build Tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out that it is not the case. Visual Studio 2015 is needed, or you can choose to install something Microsoft released separately, called Microsoft Test Agents 2015.